# BlackBerry connection on simulater working, not on device

Tags: sockets, blackberry, device, apn, access-point-name

The following code works fine on the simulator, but when I deploy it to the BlackBerry device I'm not able to connect, am I doing something wrong?

```
URL = "socket://" + server + ":" + port + ";deviceside=true;apn=internet;tunnelauthusername=;tunnelauthpassword="; 
conn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(URL);
```

Comment: you need a set tunnelauthusername and tunnelauthpassword parameters.

Comment: I'm connecting to mobile networks in South Africa, the APN settings for username and password must be left empty.

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: the exception that is caught: java.io.IOException: Timed Out

Answer (score 0):

Use this on OS5+ : http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/package-summary.html

And this if older : http://www.versatilemonkey.com/HttpConnectionFactory.java